# 401k or Roth IRA for non treaty countries

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, retirement, non-resident

This might be a bit complicated, so pretty please bear with me a little.

- I am currently living in USA on a E2 visa.
- My employer offers both 401k and Roth IRA.
- I do not plan to neither retire nor live in USA in the long run.

Should I contribue to 401k?

The problem:

- I hold two citizenships. `Country A` and `Country B`.

My E2 visa is with `Country A`, that does *not* have a tax treaty with USA.

My other citizenship in `Country B` *does* have a tax treaty with USA.

When I retire, I will most probably live in `Country B`. Will the `401k` be subject to the tax treaty of my current residency?